# I have done recycler card view as first image I want to make it as second image

Tags: android-recyclerview

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsTF7.jpg)

[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iq6OM.jpg)

I want todive the list items like image2

Comment: You should try out something and then seek for help. One cannot ask SO people to solve a problem  for oneself.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. You may want to go through [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting.

Comment: hi , thanks for your quick reply..i tried lots..but i can't able to do it

Comment: hi , i done it .. it's quit simple